# How to block completely Windows Update on my network

Tags: windows-update, block

I know it is not safe but I need to know how to prevent all computers in my LAN to download updates.

I have squid as proxy with dansguardian and I use OpenDNS...

I have put on a blacklist on dansguardian microsoft.com but it looks like it is not enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to block it in one section of our network the following domains were redirected to a site with instructions:

- update.microsoft.com
- windowsupdate.microsoft.com
- windowsupdate.com
- download.windowsupdate.com

These seem to have done the trick here, but it mightn't be the full list.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to consider, rather than blocking all updates, managing updates with [WSUS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972493). Assuming you have a copy of Windows Server and your clients are in a domain, it's a free option that you can use to only deploy updates when and where you want them.

Comment: +1 WSUS is a great way to manage Microsoft update - Central management of what updates are applied and which are not - 1 download instead of many. you could also use the GPO to fully block Microsoft Updates by pointing the update server path as an unreachable location.

Comment: Of course that will be the final aim...
Now I just need a way to block updates because there are free roaming pc, I don-t know where, killing my bandwidth

Comment: I'm with Michael and JamesK here despite my answer despite my original answer.

Comment: My question is specific...
I just need to know how to block it :)

No domain here and install manually wsus on a LOT of clients will be done in future when we'll have domain... Now I just need windows update to stop eating bandwidth for a while...

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the windows updates is a very hard task. You can't only block a few of the servers as there are many and if 1 is blocked, the updates immediately go to a different server.

You can check some of the servers here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/privacy/windows-endpoints-1709-non-enterprise-editions

Answer (score 0):

Its simple go to start menu> control panel (view by small icons)>administrative tools > services. Search for Background intelligent transfer service and windows update ...stop the services and on properties disable them

Comment: It may be *simple* but it would be tedious to do this for the dozens or hundreds of computers in the OP's network.  Could you improve this answer to apply to more than a handful of machines?  Maybe pushing out that change via a centralised system?